# How to divide a JPanel into left and right segments?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I want to divide a JPanel into left and right segments. How do I do that ? After that, I will place panels in the left and right half.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is no need to resize them, you can simply use a `BorderLayout` and insert your panels in the `BorderLayout.EAST` and `BorderLayout.WEST`:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
panel.add( leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST );
panel.add( rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST );
```

You could also consider using a [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html) which allows to resize the UI:

```
JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane( JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, 
                                  leftPanel, rightPanel );
```

Comment: +1 I'd use [`BorderLayout.LINE_START`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#LINE_START) and [`BorderLayout.LINE_END`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#LINE_END) instead :)

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy if you use a [JSPlitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html).

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways

- use GridLayout
- use JSplitPane (with hidden divider)

Answer (score 2):

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(c1, BorderLayout.WEST);
panel.add(c2, BorderLayout.EAST);

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
panel.add(c1);
panel.add(c2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) or a GridLayout

Answer (score 2):

You can use SplitPane as Costis Aivalis suggested.
Or
Use **[Border Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html)** on JPanel.
Put your left side components in WEST side and put your right side components in EAST side of layout manager.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(c1, BorderLayout.WEST);
panel.add(c2, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, rightPanel);
```

Comment: error - The constructor JSplitPane(JPanel, JPanel) is undefined

Comment: JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, rightPanel). Try this one

Answer (score 1):

```
JPanel example = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
example.add(p1);
example.add(p2);
```

Comment: did that. It messes up the gui, small buttons in left panel take the whole left side and the other components that should be on left side are not visible

Comment: how many components do you have on the left side?
if you want more than one you have to split the left panel again.

Comment: Three panels on the left side. Each panel has some components like buttons, text fields etc.

Comment: so for the left panel you could use GridLayout(3,1) and then add the buttons, text fields.. this will give you three lines.
if you want to have the buttons and text fields horizontally you can use GridLayout(1,3) this will give you three columns

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class Display{

JFrame frame=new JFrame("Drawing");
North north;
South south;
East east;
West west;
Center center;
public  int width=600,height=600;

public Display() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    frame.setSize(width,width);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(true);

    north=new North(frame);
    south=new South(frame);
    east=new East(frame);
    west=new West(frame);
    center=new Center(frame);

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


JSplitPane pane2=new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,west,east);

frame.add(pane2);

    frame.setVisible(true);

  }

 }
```